# How to enable scheduler in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

[The ActiveMQ documentation](https://%20https://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20to%20have%20a,%3D%2060%20*%201000%3B%20message) mentions this:

> ActiveMQ from version 5.4 has an optional persistent scheduler built into the ActiveMQ message broker. It is enabled by setting the broker schedulerSupport attribute to true in the Xml Configuration.

Please help me where I can find this file to update this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you cited is specifically for ActiveMQ "Classic" (i.e. 5.x and prior). It does not apply to ActiveMQ Artemis.

There is no need to configure anything for scheduled message support in ActiveMQ Artemis. It works out-of-the-box. You can read more about scheduled message support in the [ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/scheduled-messages.html).

Answer (score 0):

You enable scheduler support by adding the schedulerSupport attribute to the  tag

```
<broker .. schedulerSupport="true" ..
```

ref: [Scheduler Support documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery)

Comment: I added this to bootstrap.xml, but the activeMQ throws error on startup.

Attribute 'schedulerSupport' is not allowed to appear in element 'broker'.

also i'm using Apache Active MQ artemis not redhat

Comment: Artemis documentation here: https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/ & see Justin's answer